Effects of a hypothetical "proton-decay bomb" for a fictional story
I'm writing a science fiction story in which I need a devastating weapon of mass destruction that is far worse than nuclear bombs. For some reason, I'm fascinated by the idea of a "proton-decay bomb", a hypothetical device that triggers proton decay in a chain reaction.
I'm no physicist, and as far as I know proton decay is not something we have observed or can make happen, let alone in a chain reaction, but this doesn't really matter in the context of my story, because believe it or not, the weapon plays only a very marginal role. Nonetheless, while I am asking the reader to suspend their disbelief in terms of whether such a bomb is even possible, I would like to give a non-technical description of its probable effects that is as accurate as possible.
The way I imagine it, a proton-decay bomb would cause protons to decay in a chain reaction that eventually dies out. (If it didn't, the bomb would just be a useless doomsday device that would destroy everything, attacker included.) That is the only assumption I'm asking you to make.
Now, I must admit that up until a second ago I probably had the wrong idea about what proton decay is, as I imagined it would mean the proton splits into its three constituent quarks, but on Wikipedia it says proton decay is actually about protons turning into pions or positrons. I don't know if the proton splitting into the three quarks is at all a sensible idea, so I leave it up to whoever wants to answer if that is a possible mechanism for the bomb.
Whichever way the bomb works, I imagine the reaction would be exothermic, thus leading to a huge blast, probably an equally huge shockwave, and a flash. I also suppose other particles would be created in the process and fired all around the blast site at very high speeds, possibly causing additional damage in the form of radiation, on top of the disintegration of matter that is the main effect of the bomb. For example, if for some reason the bomb made protons decay while leaving neutrons alone, the leftover neutron radiation could spread past the area disintegrated by the blast and cause further damage to biological tissue.
Is this description at all plausible? Would there be other effects I didn't think of? Is it possible to speculate on the order of the events that would follow once the bomb is set off?
PS: I hope I chose the right tags. My apologies if I didn't!
PPS: If the idea of a proton-decay bomb is so impossible that no amount of suspension of disbelief can make up for it, alternative suggestions are welcome!

Proton decay is a prediction of supersymmetry, which is beyond the Standard Model, but it's not exactly non-mainstream, and we have many posts with the [tag:supersymmetry] tag

I’m voting to close this question because this is more suited to [worldbuilding.se]

Interesting idea for a bomb, although not wholly original:
So called sphaleron processes thought to have happenend at very early stages of the universe can convert baryon number into lepton number. Considering the fact that a proton is mich heavier than most leptons, the energy gain is indeed much more than for nuclear processes, per particle.
Now how to do this in "real life" is another question. Perhaps that thing generates enough heat to make these processes efficient again, and the process itself keeps that heat going? Or you could sprinkle in some false vacuum stories as well with beyond standard model higgs.

You could possibly say something about how a proton decay chain reaction is highly unlikely. And that quarks can't exist in isolation.

Like I said, this is not so much about how the bomb would work than it is about the practical effects it would have on a macroscopic scale.

@PM2Ring didn't op figure that out himself, that quarks can't exist in isolation? And high temperature is precisely to make this decay more likely. (Decay rate is approx. $e^{-E/T}$ whatever the symbols mean here.)

No, Nicola said "I don't know if the proton splitting into the three quarks is at all a sensible idea", and that is also in the reposted version: https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/q/257007
